# How do i save unicodes through java in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, unicode

Assuming that thefollowing three strings make up a word in chinese how do i store all these together in a single field(as one word) in the oracle

```
 String code="\u6B32 ";
 String code1="\u8ECE";
 String code2="\u4F7F";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enaugth

```
 String word = "\u6B32\u8ECE\u4F7F";

 PreparedStatement pstmt = pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(WORDS) VALUES(?)");
 pstmt.setString(1, word);

 pstmt.execute();
 pstmt.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the string as the parameter of a JDBC [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). To store Unicode you will need ask your DBA to ensure that the Oracle instance is created using a Unicode character set such as UTF-8 (or, alternatively, that the NVARCHAR type uses a Unicode character set).

Suggested Oracle settings:

- **NLS_CHARACTERSET**: AL32UTF8
- **NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS**: CHAR

You can check the NLS parameters by issuing the following query:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters
```

Since you will be saving Chinese characters I suggest you read up on [Unicode supplementary characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) and their [implementation in Oracle DB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch5.htm#1019933). Each Unicode character set stores supplementary characters differently, and this can have a significant affect on the size of your DB on disk. Also, length semantics can be more complicated because there is no longer a 1:1 relationship between # of code points and # of characters.

Further reading:

- [Choosing a Character Set](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch2.htm)
- [Supporting Multilingual Databases with Unicode](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch5.htm)
- [Java Programming in a Global Environment](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch9.htm)
- [Collation in Oracle using NLS_SORT](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/collation-in-oracle-using-nls_sort)